# google cloud vm & putty - after moving I get "Network error: Software caused connection abort"

Tags: ssh, putty, google-cloud-platform

I hope this is the correct place to post this question. I apologize if not.

Let me start by saying this is NOT a keepalives issue. My bot is running 24/7 so there is, at least to my knowledge, no need for keepalives. I've done research and cannot find a good answer. I apologize in advance for the read as my issue requires some context.

I use gcloud VM's to run a bot 24/7 that computes stuff. I connect to the Putty SSH using Google Cloud SDK Shell via my local Windows 10. I've had no issues with it for the past 6-7 months, but recently I moved back into my mom's place as I finish college for financial reasons. She has never had problems with her internet, nor did I when I lived there back in 2022. Since moving about a week ago every 24-48 hours I get the error: "Network error: Software caused connection abort". I use an ethernet cable for a consistent connection to the internet. My internet is plenty good getting a ping of ~30ms, a download of 200mbps, and an upload of ~150mbps.

I am at a loss because this just started happening since I moved and I have not changed anything except my internet, which I don't see how that is an issue. Additionally, I do not think my internet is disconnecting because I afk some online video games I play and I don't get kicked from those. I tried running the program in the background with the "&" cmd. i.e. 'python3 main.py &'. This also seems not to work. Finally, I ran google's Internet Connectivity Monitor (https://code.google.com/archive/p/internetconnectivitymonitor/) to see if maybe it is my ISP losing packets, but no issues were detected.

To recap:
Never had issues in the past 7 months,
Recently moved,
Not a KeepAlives issue because the bot runs 24/7 on a while True loop,
Most likely my internet is not disconnecting,
Running the bot in the background doesn't work,
google's Internet Connectivity Monitor detected no issues

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a mom's ISP issue. Maybe some IP rollover or whatever internally that isnt noticable except for persistent connections.

Comment: @Silbee I updated the post to note that I ran google's Internet Connectivity Monitor. It found no issues with my ISP.

Comment: Mind you, google ICM intermittently checks the connection, much like a simple ping would. Do you have any other ssh host you could connect to that would allow you to stay connected 24/7 and see if that shows the same problem ?